# Gnuplot x-axis range Represents Frames, MD simulation, DSSP plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I plotted my *.gnu* file in gnuplot. This plot x-axis range `[0.000:7002.000]`, this data separated with xtic values as `0,1000,2000,.......7000` (frame numbers) on x axis.
I would like to change/multiply/transform  these frame numbers into nanoseconds, so that my x-axis values are shown as `0,1,2......14(ns)` after multiplying with `.002`.
Here are some lines of my *.gnu* file:

```
set   pm3d   map  corners2color c1
set   ytics     1.000,    1.000
set ytics   ("HM1_187@O2D-SER_137@OG-HG"    1.000,"HM1_187@O1D-SER_137@OG-HG"    2.000)
set xlabel "Frame"
set ylabel ""
set yrange [   0.000:   4.000]
set xrange [   0.000:7002.000]
splot "-" with pm3d title "hhhh.gnu"


   1.000    1.000             1
   1.000    2.000             0
   1.000    3.000 0

   2.000    1.000             1
   2.000    2.000             1
   2.000    3.000 0

   3.000    1.000             0
   3.000    2.000             1
   3.000    3.000 0

   4.000    1.000             0
   4.000    2.000             0
   4.000    3.000 0

   5.000    1.000             1
   5.000    2.000             0
   5.000    3.000 0

   6.000    1.000             1
   6.000    2.000             0
   6.000    3.000 0
```

and so on.

How can I change my x axis tics to nanoseconds rather then frames numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your question to make it a little more readable. However, you left some of the placeholder texts from the SO editor in the code. I tried to remove them but please check that everything is still correct.

Comment: Then do that multiplication: `splot "-" using (0.002*$1):2:3`